# Convert an int to a string saved in a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, string, listview, int, dataadapter

I have a SQL Server database with a table `Event_Tab` with an `Int` column `Code`. I want to associate this `Code` with a specific `string` and this so I don't save string variable in my table.

So, I wrote a procedure `GetStringCode` with In16 input parameter and it returns the string that I need, then I fill it in a listview with the other parameter saved in my table

This is my code to do it :

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(table);

    foreach(DataRow dr in table.Rows)
    {
        ListViewItem items = new ListViewItem(dr["Machine"].ToString());                    
        items.SubItems.Add(GetStringCode((short)dr["Code"]).ToString());
        items.SubItems.Add(dr["Date_time"].ToString());
        listview.Items.Add(items);
    }
}
```

If you notice, I did a cast to get rid of an error

> Cannot convert from object to short

and so far everything seems okay. But when a try to run this code, I am getting an error

> The specific cast is invalid

What is the problem because I can't seem to find it...

Comment: What is the content for the 'DataRow dr` when the error occurs? Perhaps **"Code"** is empty or null.

Comment: @Stringfellow, it's not empty i checked my table data, it has number

Comment: Start by inspecting the value and actual type of `dr["Code"]` in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be running into an issue with unboxing, rather than type casting. A variable of type int will cast to short. However, a boxed int will not cast directly to short. A boxed value type can be directly cast only to the exact boxed type.

```
int i = 100;
object o = i; // Boxed int.
short s1 = (short) i; // Works.
short s2 = (short) o; // Throws InvalidCastException.
short s3 = (short) (int) o; // Works.
```

`DataRow` stores field values as `object`, so value types are boxed. That means that attempting to cast a field value that is a boxed int, directly to short, is causing the issue. A two-stage cast (as in s3 above) may solve the problem.

[What is the difference between boxing/unboxing and type casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085144/what-is-the-difference-between-boxing-unboxing-and-type-casting)

Comment: it worked thanks, i will go check about the boxing/unboxing because it's the first time i encountered it

Answer (score 0):

If the SQL table is defining the column for **Code** as below:

```
CREATE TABLE Event_Tab (
    Machine varchar(255),
    Code int,
    Date_time datetime
);
```

Then the datatype coming from SQL will not cast to C#'s `short` or `Int16` because SQL `int` is equivalent to C# `Int32` ([Data Type Mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726019(v=sql.110).aspx))

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Machine", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(SqlInt32));
    table.Columns.Add("Date_time", typeof(DateTime));

    DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
    dr.ItemArray = new object[] { "machineA", 1122, DateTime.Now };

    // Works
    Int32 i32 = ((SqlInt32)dr["Code"]).Value;

    // Throws 'Specified cast is not valid.'
    Int16 i16 = (short)dr["Code"];
}
```

Comment: are you suggesting that a change my code column type to SqlInt32? because i don't even have this column type as a choice, and i couldn't do the cast in c# with SqlInt32 it deosn't recognize it

Comment: No, not suggesting to use `SqlInt32`. Was trying to demonstrate how the type from SQL may not be matching the type in C#, causing the invalid cast exception. Was hoping to imply using the debugger to dig deeper into the datatype returned from SQL and in the DataTable. By the way, `SqlInt32` is in `using System.Data.SqlTypes;`