# Upcasting and down-casting is also boxing and unboxing?

Tags: casting, boxing

I'm new to OOP
and I have a question about these concept
Do the upcasting and down-casting and boxing and unboxing have the same meaning is C#?
Upcasting and down-casting is also  boxing and unboxing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between boxing/unboxing and type casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085144/what-is-the-difference-between-boxing-unboxing-and-type-casting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boxing/unboxing is kind a special case of type casting.

Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object or to any interface type implemented by this value type.

Boxing does allocate additional memory as a new reference type is created. Also, boxing process needs the value to be *not* nullable.

So as you see, boxing is more specific process comparing to type casting, and still they share similar nature.