# Why does (int)(object)10m throw "Specified cast is not valid" exception?

Tags: c#, casting

Why this explicit cast does throw `Specified cast is not valid.` exception ?

```
decimal d = 10m;
object o = d;
int x = (int)o;
```

But this works:

```
int x = (int)(decimal)o;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I unbox an int as a decimal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085097/why-cant-i-unbox-an-int-as-a-decimal)

Comment: Other questions/duplicates all combining to a full answer: [Why can't I unbox an int as a decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1085097/11683), [Cast object containing int to float results in InvalidCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24447387/11683), [Casting object to int throws InvalidCastException in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39891504/11683)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

A boxed value can only be unboxed to a variable of the exact same type.  This seemingly odd restriction is a very important speed optimization that made .NET 1.x feasible before generics were available.  You can read more about it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583050/performance-surprise-with-as-and-nullable-types/3076525#3076525).

You don't want to jump through the multiple cast hoop, simple value types implement the IConvertible interface.  Which you invoke by using the Convert class:

```
        object o = 12m;
        int ix = Convert.ToInt32(o);
```

Answer (score 23):

When you do this, you're implicitly boxing the decimal `d` to a basic object:

```
object o = d;
```

You cannot cast boxed values directly without first unboxing them, which is why casting directly to an int, as in the following, fails:

```
int x = (int)o;
```

However, by doing this (intermediately casting to a decimal first):

```
int x = (int)(decimal)o;
```

You're first unboxing `o`, which means you're retrieving the decimal value, *then* casting the unboxed decimal value to an int, which works because C# supports casting decimals to ints.

Answer (score 10):

`decimal` has an [explicit cast operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf02hx8s.aspx) to `int`. `object` does not:

```
decimal d = 10m;
object o = d;
int x = (int)d;  // OK, calls decimal.explicit operator int(d).
int y = (int)o;  // Invalid cast.
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need to think of here is that boxing and unboxing is not exactly a kind of conversion. You just "wrap" the object type "around" the initial decimal-type. That is why you need to unbox the object first, before you are able to convert it to an integer.