# C# casting int to float throwing exception (in runtime)

Tags: c#, casting, floating-point, int

This throws an exception that say the source can't be casted to destination:

```
int a = 1;
object b = (object)a;
float c = (float)b; // Exception here
```

Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why \[ (int)(object)10m; \] does throw "Specified cast is not valid" exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953391/why-intobject10m-does-throw-specified-cast-is-not-valid-exception)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only cast boxed structs to the exact type, so you'll need to cast a to int first:

```
float c = (float)(int)b;
```

However since there's an implicit conversion to float from int, you can just do:

```
float c = (int)b;
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it's because you box "a" as an int and after that you unbox it as a float and this wont work...

to get it right you should do float c = (float) (int) b;

Answer (score 1):

You can't unbox (cast to object and back) a value from one data type to another. You would need to bring it back to its original type first, then pull it out. Alternatively, you can use the `Convert.To*` methods, e.g.

```
Object a = 6;
Double b = Convert.ToDouble(a);
```

Follow-up: http://www.ideone.com/hgeob

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the same syntax is reused for 3 operations (historical problem from C):

1. Boxing/unboxing the value
2. Converting numbers
3. Casting

```
int a = 1; // Ok
object b = (object)a; // Ok. int is struct so we may box it into object
float c = (float)a; // Ok. Conversion from integer to float
float c = (float)b; // Error. object b is not boxed float
```

Comment: UL/OLs are funny with the parser, you need to add something between them. In this case I used an arbitrary bogus HTML tag (as to invoke formatting, but not interfere with the post itself).