# Casting object that has short value to int in C#

Tags: c#

Consider this code:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    short age = 123;
    object ageObject = age;
    //var intAge = (int)ageObject;//Specified cast is not valid.
    int newAge= (short)intAge;
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I have to assign a short value to object and again cast to int, but when I try to this: `var intAge = (int)ageObject;` I get : **Specified cast is not valid**. I don't know why?

After search in google i found that should cast to short and assign to int:`int newAge= (short)intAge;`

Why we should casting to short and assign to int?

Why compiler has this behavior?

Comment: It works perfect on my end...

Comment: When unboxing a struct you have to cast to the exact type, `short` in this case. From there you can convert to an `int`.

Comment: `(int)(short)ageObject;` works

Comment: This link will explain you why [Representation and identity](http://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/)

Comment: I can't comment I'm still new to the community, your answer is here: <br/> [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953391/why-does-intobject10m-throw-specified-cast-is-not-valid-exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953391/why-does-intobject10m-throw-specified-cast-is-not-valid-exception)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does (int)(object)10m throw "Specified cast is not valid" exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953391/why-does-intobject10m-throw-specified-cast-is-not-valid-exception)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The failure is a runtime error.

The reason for it is the `age` value has been boxed into an object; unboxing it to the incorrect type (`int`) is a failure - it's a `short`.

The cast on the line which you've commented out is an unboxing operation, not just a cast.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Convert.ToInt32(ageObject) instead.
```

It will work

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand why you are trying to convert short to object and then int.

You could do short -> int conversion in following ways:

```
{
short age = 123;
int intAge1 = (short)age;
int intAge2 = (int)age;
int intAge3 = Int16.Parse(age.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A boxed value can only be unboxed to a variable of the exact same type
This restriction helped in  speed optimization that made .NET 1.x feasible before generics came into picture.Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583050/performance-surprise-with-as-and-nullable-types/3076525#3076525)

simple value types implement the IConvertible interface.  Which you invoke by using the Convert class

```
      short age= 123;
    int ix = Convert.ToInt32(age);
```