# Casting object to int throws InvalidCastException in C#

Tags: c#, casting, unboxing

I have this method:

```
private static Dossier PrepareDossier(List<List<object>> rawDossier)
{
    return new Dossier((int)rawDossier[0][0]);
}
```

When I use it I get an `InvalidCastException`. However, when I use `Convert.ToInt32(rawDossier[0][0])` it works just fine. What is the problem?

Comment: What _is_ the type of the object stored at `rawDossier[0][0]`? If it is for example a `string` containing a valid number, `Convert.ToInt32()` will work just fine but the cast will of course throw.

Comment: (edited) You cannot unbox a box with one numeric type into another numeric type. Also, like @RenéVogt says, you cannot convert a reference to a string to a value type with the cast syntax.

Comment: What does `rawDossier[0][0] ?. GetType().ToString()` give?

Comment: It's a `string`. I actually get it from the database, and I did not know that it retrieves it as a string. Thank you all.

Comment: Other questions/duplicates all combining to a full answer: [Why does (int)(object)10m throw “Specified cast is not valid” exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3953391/11683), [Cast object containing int to float results in InvalidCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24447387/11683), [Why can't I unbox an int as a decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1085097/11683)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that you don't *cast* an `object` to an `int`, you're attempting to *unbox* an int.

The object really has to be an int. It cannot be just anything that can be *converted* to an int.

So the difference is that this:

```
int a = (int)obj;
```

Really needs `obj` to be a boxed `int`, nothing else, whereas this:

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32(obj);
```

Will execute the `ToInt32` method which will try to figure out what is really going on and do the right thing.

The "right thing" here is to ensure the object in question implements [`IConvertible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible(v=vs.110).aspx) and calling [`IConvertible.ToInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.touint32(v=vs.110).aspx), as is evident from the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1024):

```
public static int ToInt32(object value) {
    return value == null? 0: ((IConvertible)value).ToInt32(null);
}
```

You can see the unboxing on [try roslyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:>ilr/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3ay+BAFapSyGPIUwAvDACMABhyzZkVWC0wxJiesPsAvtjtA==):

```
IL_0007: unbox.any [mscorlib]System.Int32
```

**Conclusion**: The object you're trying to unbox is not an `int`, but it is something that can be converted to an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess this is because the object in your list is not an int.

Convert.ToInt32 will convert other non-int types so works.

Check what is being passed in to the method.

Answer (score 2):

When you try to unbox `int` from an `object`, the boxed value should be `int`, otherwise you will receive an exception, while `Convert.ToInt32` uses `IConvertible` implementation of boxed type to convert the value to int.

For example if the value which is boxed is string `"100"`, unboxing it will throw an exception but using `Convert.ToInt32`, internally uses `int.Parse`.

> [Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)
>
> Attempting to unbox a reference to an incompatible value type causes
> an InvalidCastException.