# C# Integer casting

Tags: c#, oop, types, .net-core, casting

I'm trying to do the following

```
int num = 20;
object number = num;
int result = (int)num;
```

It's yelling "Invalid cast" at me because, from what the compiler says:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Int32

Can you please explain why my Int32 became an Int64?

Comment: cannot reproduce. Your code works like a charm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891504/casting-object-to-int-throws-invalidcastexception-in-c-sharp

Comment: [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KfR1mc) ← Code works fine.

Comment: I suspect that the code you post is slightly different than the real problem. Are you perhaps trying to cast a `long` to an `object` and then to an `int`?

Comment: @itsme86: why you are suprised? The variable `number` is never used and `num` is still `20`. @OP: Show the real code

Answer (score 1):

`object number = num;` is not a cast, but [boxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing)!

While all reference types inherit from Object - explicitly or implicitly Value Types do not have a inheritance chain. Instead they get boxed into a instance of...something. That is then cast into the object.

And apparently that instance takes [Int64 rather then Int32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types). For one reason or another, the option to put a Int32 into a Box that takes only Int32 is never even considered.

There is no longer a real reason to do this anyway. With things like Generics, you can get around most needs to box value types ever.