# C# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Single'

Tags: c#, .net, casting, type-conversion, precision

before judging that this question is already answered, please read the description. I have this simple code below:

```
Dictionary<string, object> d = new Dictionary<string, object>();

d.Add("key" , 30d);

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($" TYPE OF OBJECT IS  \"{d["key"].GetType()}\"");

netPlannedHours = (float)d["key"];         ---> **Line of Interest**
```

When i execute this i get:

> TYPE OF OBJECT IS  "System.Double" Exception thrown:
> 'System.InvalidCastException' in  DevOpsAutomatedReporting.dll Unable
> to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Single'.

The exception is caused by the last line tagged "Line of interest". I can't really understand why the last line is causing this as the type of the object is inferred to be "System.Double" at runtime so it should've had cast it to a float but it doesn't. An interesting point is that if i replace the last line ("Line of interest") with either of the following two lines of code it successfully converts the double to float

```
// Cast the double object to double again and then to float **WORKS**
netPlannedHours = (float)(double)d["key"];
  
// Convert to float using "Convert.ToSingle()"  **WORKS**
netPlannedHours = Convert.ToSingle(d["key"]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast object containing int to float results in InvalidCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447387/cast-object-containing-int-to-float-results-in-invalidcastexception)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting object to int throws InvalidCastException in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39891504/11683)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does (int)(object)10m throw “Specified cast is not valid” exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3953391/11683)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I unbox an int as a decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1085097/11683)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you add to the dictionary your double will be boxed, as the dictionary is mapping a `string` to an `object`.

When you unbox you must cast to the underlying type. In your case that underlying type is a `double`, so the cast to `float` will fail.

You can get around this by using [Convert.ToSingle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tosingle?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToSingle_System_Object_)

```
netPlannedHours = Convert.ToSingle(d["key"])
```

This method will work out the underlying type and can do the conversion, at the expense of a performance hit when working out the type conversions.

Comment: .. as the dictionary is mapping a `double` ... I guess

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem today with my SQL entity mapped as "float" and my .Net entity mapped as "float".  I kept the SQL mapping, though changed the .Net types to "double".

The ADO.NET [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) documentation presents a table of the correct mapping for all types.

Comment: This is a very good solution when you're mapping SQL entity with .Net entity so if you're experiencing the same problem check it out

Answer (score 4):

I recently had a similar problem. In my case the problem was with the data types between SQL and C#. The **real** data type in SQL Server is equivalent to **Single** in C#. I quote the original answer

*"SQL Server real is equivalent to C# Single and SQL server float is equivalent to C# Double."*
[System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Single'.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62337101/system-invalidcastexception-unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-double-to-t)

I hope it can be useful to other people