# System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Single'.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, floating-point, double

Hy,
I'm getting this error on line  _obj.Add(new data()...
here is my code

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_get_a", con)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        };
        _obj = new List<n>();
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                _obj.Add(new data() { Id = rdr.GetInt32(0), na = rdr.GetString(1), Al = rdr.GetString(2), Sc = rdr.GetFloat(3), So = rdr.GetInt32(4), Ta = rdr.GetInt32(5), Ai = rdr.GetInt32(6), Sh = rdr.GetInt32(7) });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("rdr don't have any rows");
        }
        con.Close();
```

my stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_get_a
```

AS
SELECT Id, Na, Al, Sc, So, Ta, Ai, Sh
FROM x
I don't have any double value and closest to double is Sc(float). so I tried Sc = Convert.ToSingle(rdr.GetFloat(3)).
Where am I doing wrong ?
Edit- My model

```
public class n
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Na { get; set; }
    public string Al { get; set; }
    public float Sc { get; set; }
    public int So { get; set; }
    public int Ta { get; set; }
    public int Ai { get; set; }
    public int Sh { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what is `new List<n>();?

Comment: what is datatype in database for this column??

Comment: You are receiving a 64 bit double and you cannot convert the number to a 32 bit float. because the range of a 32 bit double is not large enough to convert the number.  You need to change the type of Sc from a float to a double.

Comment: Hy Vivek, List<n> is my model class. and datatype in database is same as shown in my public class n.
Hy jdweng, Thank you. It solved my problem. I'd liketo know why I'm receiving 64 bit double(I'm assuming coming from database) even though it is stored as float.
Also I'd like to ask why is it trying to convert to single by itself ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to change the datatype of `Sc` from `float` to `double`

SQL Server `real` is equivalent to C# `Single` and SQL server `float` is equivalent to C# `Double`.

And you should consider @jdweng point also

Comment: Hy Vivek, Thank you for your equivalent explanation. This also clears why was it trying to convert itself even though I didn't tried to convert anything.
@Jdwend point was helpful as well.