# Why can't C# cast an object containing a boxed int to a double?

Tags: c#, casting, integer, double, boxing

In C#, why does Example 1 work:

```
int myValue1 = 11;
double resultDirectlyFromInt = myValue1;
```

But Example 2 does not:

```
int myValue2 = 22;
object myObject2 = myValue2;
double resultFromBoxedInt = (double)myObject2;
```

Yet again Example 3 does work:

```
double myValue3 = 33.3;
object myObject3 = myValue3;
double resultFromBoxedDouble = (double)myObject3;
```

Can someone explain the rationale behind that ? Because to me, working examples 1 and 3 look like proofs that example 2 should work.

Comment: You can use Convert.ToDouble(myObject2).  The c# language just doesn't support casting from int to double.  c# does support setting an int to a double without casting.  It is just a quirk in the language.

Comment: "The c# language just doesn't support casting from int to double." Yes it does, as both an implicit or explicit conversion. It doesn't support *unboxing* a boxed int to double.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Because to me, working examples 1 and 3 look like proofs that example 2 should work.

No, they're very different conversions.

C# defines a conversion from `int` to `double` (see [section 10.2.3](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v7/standard/conversions.md#1023-implicit-numeric-conversions) of the C# 7 draft standard). But unboxing conversions are defined very differently, in [section 10.3.7](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v7/standard/conversions.md#1037-unboxing-conversions):

> An unboxing operation to a *non_nullable_value_type* consists of first checking that the object instance is a boxed value of the given *non_nullable_value_type*, and then copying the value out of the instance.
>
> ...
>
> If the source operand is a reference to an incompatible object, a `System.InvalidCastException` is thrown.

In your example 2, the object instance is *not* a boxed value of type `double` - it's a boxed value of type `int`, so the check described above fails.

As it happens, the .NET CLR is a little more forgiving in terms of unboxing than C# requires; you can unbox from a boxed `int` to a `uint` or vice versa, and also from an enum to its underlying type or vice versa. But it doesn't permit anything that requires a *representation* change, like `int` to `double`.

If you want a *justification* for those rules, think of it this way: in order to perform any conversion that performs real work (as opposed to just copying a bit pattern from one place to another), the compiler needs to tell the CLR which conversion to perform. For an unboxing operation, the *actual* type is only known at execution time, so the compiler can't instruct the CLR what to do. The CLR could have more complex rules so that *it* could perform the conversion based on the execution-time type - but that's straying into territory that is usually language-based.

Comment: Feel bad for not up-voting your answer :)... While I like (and agree with) the justification part (which is what OP seem to be asking for) I don't think it's authoritative enough. I don't know if such explanation actually exists somewhere so...

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeet. I get the concept now.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov While the links to thedocs are valuable, I fell your edits changed the tone of my question which was not necessary. Perhaps the links and implied comments would have been better in an answer.

Comment: @GillesjrBisson sorry. Will keep to my "downvote and move on" next time. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is actually calling the operator called `implicit conversion operator`, which you can find more info in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double?view=net-7.0#type-conversions-and-the-double-structure), and this happen to be implemented in compiler level. The reason why it works is compiler knows that `Int32` integers can be represent fully in a `Double`-type variable during compile time.

In your example 2, the reason why it does not work is it during unbox, you must cast it back to the original type first, so that the runtime can ensure the type safety. [Reference to other answers as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57107841).
Instead, you can change the example 2 as below so that it will run without runtime complaining, which is kind of explaining how example 1 works under-the-hood with the cast to double, but explicitly.

```cs
int myValue2 = 22;
object myObject2 = myValue2;
double resultFromBoxedInt = (double)(int)myObject2;
```

Comment: The reason I can't do that in my project is that the boxed value I am trying to cast to double may be originally either an int or a double. So I guess Convert.ToDouble() is my way to go.