# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. How to cast object of type system.double to system.single?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, exception, error-handling

I have encountered this error when I try to create new product. When I click the create button, this is what it shows.

[image]

This is my table in my database.

[image]

Although the data I entered when I was trying to create a new product goes inside the database I created.

[image]

This is my program in C#

```
public partial class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Product Image")]
    public string? ProductImage { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Product Name")]
    public string? ProductName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Serial Number")]
    public string? ProductSerialNo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Product Description")]
    public string? ProductDescription { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Product Price")]
    public int ProductPrice { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Product Shape")]
    public string? ProductShape { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Product Carat")]
    public double ProductCarat { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Product Cut")]
    public string? ProductCut { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Product Color")]
    public string? ProductColor { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Product Clarity")]
    public string? ProductClarity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Product Polish")]
    public string? ProductPolish { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Product Symmetry")]
    public string? ProductSymmetry { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Product Fluorescence")]
    public string? ProductFluo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Product Table")]
    public double ProductTable { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Product Depth")]
    public double ProductDepth { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Product Culet")]
    public string? ProductCulet { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Product Length/Width Ratio")]
    public double ProductLWR { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Product Remarks")]
    public string? ProductRemarks { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone help me solve this error? Thank you!

Comment: Try create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or use solution provided in this post [C# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Single'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57107841/6630084)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)