# Oracle.DataAccess DataRow.Field<decimal> InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, oracle

In my code I was using `System.Data.OracleClient` for ora database connection. I would like to replace this library (because it is obsolete) with `Oracle.DataAccess`. Unfortunately I found that DataRow.Field() throws `InvalidCastException`. Same behavior is with `(decimal)x.Rows[0]["COLUME_NAME"]`. I do not have this issue with `System.Data.OracleClient`.

Here is code example

```
using (var oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var command = new OracleCommand("select * from tr", oracleConnection))
    {
        var result = new DataTable();
        var adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(result);
        Console.WriteLine(result.Rows[0].Field<decimal>("TR_SEQ_NUM"));
        //Console.WriteLine((decimal)result.Rows[0]["TR_SEQ_NUM"]);
    }
}
```

TR_SEQ_NUM has `NUMBER(8,0)` datatype and full exception is:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.ValueField(Object value)
```

Code example working with `System.Data.OracleClient` but not with `Oracle.DataAccess`

I know that I can use `Convert.ChangeType` but I wonder if there is some way to have same behavior as with `System.Data.OracleClient`. Refactoring of all of my code will too much time expensive.

Comment: using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client; //use the managed version
What happens when you call tbl.Rows[0][0].GetType(); ?
.Field isn't possble in the new version you use column indexes/names. You are going to have to refactor, System.Data.OracleClient is way out of date but the casting should be handled for you when you fill the table...

Comment: Also, Number(8,0) would not be a decimal, why are you casting it to one? It's very rare that Decimal's need to be used, not that it would cause the issue you are having but that might save you some memory when the app is running

Comment: I agree with _LessNoviceProgrammer_. I think the correct type for `NUMBER(8,0)` is `int`...

Answer (score 2):

The value in the database is not a decimal and a boxed int (the 'value' parameter in the error message) cannot be cast to a decimal, despite casting an int to a decimal being OK. [This answer leads to more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953391/why-does-intobject10m-throw-specified-cast-is-not-valid-exception).

You can see it in action with this:

```
void Main()
{
    int anInt = 5;
    object boxedInt = (object)anInt;
    decimal unboxed = Convert.ToDecimal(boxedInt); //5
    decimal unboxed2 = (decimal)boxedInt; //InvalidCastException
}
```

If you look at the Unbox.ValueField method, it does...

```
  private static T ValueField(object value)
  {
    if (DBNull.Value == value)
      throw DataSetUtil.InvalidCast(Strings.DataSetLinq_NonNullableCast((object) typeof (T).ToString()));
    return (T) value;
  }
```

Basically you'll need to

```
Convert.ToDecimal(rows[0]["TR_SEQ_NUM"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks your data contains null value and you cannot convert a nullable data to non nullable decimal type

Please use the below statment to read the nullable decimal column from DB

```
result.Rows[0].Field<decimal?>("TR_SEQ_NUM")
```