# char cast vs Convert.ToChar()

Tags: c#, sql-server, char

I have a char type column in table. I want to convert it to a char in C#.
It is working by

```
char gender = Convert.ToChar(dataRow["Gender"]);
```

But it failed

```
 char gender = (char)(dataRow["Gender"]);
```

If a column is int type. I can use (int) to cast an object.
Why it failed on char(exception)?

InValidCastException.

Thanks,

Comment: In what way does it fail?  If it throws an exception, please say what the exception is.  If it fails to compile, please say what the compile error is.  If it just fails to get the right value, please give an example.

Comment: What is the return type of dataRow?

Comment: Invalid cast from what to what?  Surely it specifies...

Comment: Similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085097/why-cant-i-unbox-an-int-as-a-decimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `datarow[column]` is an expression of type **'object'**

The `Convert.ToChar()` method has an overload that takes an object as argument, so the compiler knows what to do.

The `(char)dataRow[column]` is an explicit cast of `dataRow[column]` to the char type, but an automatic  conversion from object to char doesn't exist

Comment: Do you mean (char) take a char object as an argument?

Comment: The compiler doesn't complain. I think you mean the runtime. Also the issue comes from trying to unbox as a different type. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1085105/442078

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `dataRow["Gender"])` contains an `int` value. This means it's a "boxed" int (an 'int' stored as an object). You can only cast that to a "real" int, you can't directly convert it to something else, like a `char`.

You can however use a two-step approach:

```
char gender = (char)(int)dataRow["Gender"];
```

- first cast the boxed `int` ro a real one
- then convert that int to a `char`.

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToChar` reads the text value "A" and converts it into a character object with the value "A".

Casting assumes the original value IS a character object.  The error tells you it is not.

Answer (score 0):

**Most** probabbly the **real** value in the *cell* is of type `object`.
In *this* case you **will** get `InvalidCastException`.

[Convert.ToChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms130985.aspx) works, instead, cause there is an overload that accepts `object` type.

Answer (score 0):

If `dataRow["Gender"]` is in fact a (strongly typed) string, you could use

```
char g = dataRow["Gender"][0];
```

to get the zeroth character of that string (would fail if the string was `null` or empty). If, on the other hand, `dataRow["Gender"]` is a string but is typed as `System.Object`, you could use

```
char g = ((string)dataRow["Gender"])[0];
```