# invalid cast exception on int to double

Tags: c#, linq, casting, linqpad

Maybe I'm crazy, but I thought this was a valid cast:

```
(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}).Cast<double>()
```

Why is LinqPad throwing a

> InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

?

Comment: Also see [why-cant-i-unbox-an-int-as-a-decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085097/why-cant-i-unbox-an-int-as-a-decimal). Very closely related..

Answer (score 40, accepted):

C# allows a conversion from `int` directly to `double`, but not from `int` to `object` to `double`.

```
int i = 1;
object o = i;
double d1 = (double)i; // okay
double d2 = (double)o; // error
```

The `Enumerable.Cast` extension method behaves like the latter. It does not convert values to a different type, it asserts that values are already of the expected type and throws an exception if they aren't.

You could try `(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}).Select(i => (double)i)` instead to get the value-converting behaviour.

Comment: Another way to think of it is that the C# cast operator (brackets) does both explicit type coercion (int -> double) and typecasting (checked conversion of references from one type to another compatible reference).  But Linq's Cast method just does the latter.

Comment: @OliverBock That's a valid way to think of it, but to be honest, I don't think that distinction you're making between naming the two meanings of casts is widely accepted.

Comment: Oops! But I'm wondering why it is failing for `value types`. Had it been a case of two `reference type` variables where one of the two types was castable to the other one then this wouldn't have failed. I'm wondering why C# has implemented it this way just for `value types` when every type in CTS inherits from `System.Object`?

Comment: Interestingly, this code 
`object obj = 2;
double d1 = (double)i; // okay`
gives no error. I'm sure here 2 must have been implicitly considered as an integer by the run-time while getting assigned to `obj`.

Comment: @RBT `(double)i` might not give an error, but `(double)obj` should.