# c# generic can not instead object type

Tags: c#

```
public class Calculate
{
    public static T Add<T>(T a, T b) where T : struct
    {
        return (T)((object)(Convert.ToDouble(a) + Convert.ToDouble(b)));
    }
}
```

run Calculate.Add(10, 20) will get error,why?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Explain the problem.

Comment: You've ensured that the result of the addition is of type `double`. You then box that and try to unbox it as an `int`. Outside of some special options for enums, you can't unbox to a different datatype to what was boxed.

Comment: Not sure why you are converting to double and then casting to double, as this is causing boxing and unboxng.  When calling method just do 10d, 20d or whatever type of calculation you want. In the method just use a+ b;

Comment: See [invalid cast exception on int to double](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12647068/6400526) and [Why do I get InvalidCastException when casting a double to decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667169/why-do-i-get-invalidcastexception-when-casting-a-double-to-decimal)

Comment: When returning, he is casting object to "T" and its throwing InvalidCast exception.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - its a runtime error since the `Convert` class exposes overloads that take `object`s.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: yeah, I realized that as soon as I hit Enter

Comment: Please explain the problem more so you could get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
 return (T)Convert.ChangeType(Convert.ToDouble(a) + Convert.ToDouble(b), typeof(T));
```

It will convert your result to type "T".

Comment: thank you it runs right. my english is poor ,question describes so bad