# Invalid cast exception generics

Tags: c#

I'm having this issue, I'm using reflection to pull properties from a class but the problem is reflection returns them as an object and I can't get it into my actual type.

Take for example, if this is the class:

```
public class Row<T>
{
    public static explicit operator Row<object>(Row<T> o)
    {
        return new Row<object>
        {
            Name = o.Name,
            Value = o.Value
        };
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Casting from one say `Row<bool>` to `Row<object>` works:

```
    var a = new Row<bool>
    {
        Name = "Foo",
        Value = true
    };

    var b = (Row<object>)a; // Works
```

But when I try to go from `object` to `Row<object>` it seems to ignore my explicit operator and throw a System.InvalidCastException:

```
var c = (object) a; // Simulate getting from reflection

var d = (Row<object>) c; // System.InvalidCastException
```

What am I missing?

Comment: do it like this var c = (Row<object>) a;

Comment: Not sure what you expect - there is no `explicit operator Row<object>(object o)` in your sample...

Comment: This may be because the explicit operator expects a `Row<T>` whereas you are giving it an `object`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, that is clear, but the question is - even if he defined `explicit operator Row<object>(object o)`, how would he define it?

Comment: @NoOne I'm using reflection (GetPropertyValue) which returns an object

Comment: @JLRishe You cannot define an explicit conversion from `object`

Comment: Getting property via reflection does not change its type... Since you do know type of property you can explicitly construct `Row<type of property>`.... I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to - show an actual type (like `(object)1` is result of getting integer property via reflection...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I unbox an int as a decimal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085097/why-cant-i-unbox-an-int-as-a-decimal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that casting does not look for a conversion operator unless one is defined on the static type of the value you are trying to cast. In your example the static type of `c` is `object` and `object` neither derives from nor has a conversion operator to `Row<object>`, resulting in the runtime exception.

It looks like this problem can be easily sidestepped with a better design.

You want to treat any type of `Row<T>` as a `Row<object>` and the conversion operator does nothing more  than work around the fact that these types are not hierarchically related. So why not make them related and avoid the problem in the first place?

For example:

```
public abstract class Row
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; protected set; }
}

public class Row<T> : Row
{
    public new T Value
    { 
        get { return (T)base.Value; }
        set { base.Value = value; }
    }
}
```

This seems to do what you want:

- The casting problem is solved because you can now cast any type of `Row<T>` to the base class `Row` (which takes over the responsibilities of `Row<object>` in your initial design) and easily access `Name` and `Value` no matter what type the `Value` is.
- The `Row.Value` setter is protected so you cannot cast a `Row<int>` to `Row` and make `Value` e.g. a `string` from outside, maintaining type safety.

Comment: Wow, just testing this design now, initially looks like it does indeed solve the root cause (not so great design). Need to order Jon Skeet's book...

Answer (score 6):

Use `dynamic` instead of `object` to force runtime real type check:

```
var c = (dynamic)a;
var d = (Row<object>)c; // Works fine
```

It will call your `Row<T> -> Row<object>` cast operator.

Comment: You cannot declare `explicit operator Row<object>(object o)`.

Comment: Visual Studio complains... so I should first cast the object reflection returns to dynamic then to my type?

Comment: @Phil Yes, that is what Marcin is suggesting. You can do this: `var d = (Row<object>)(dynamic)c;`.

Comment: I am lodging a formal complaint against this answer because what it does is *make the problem go away*. It does not attempt to explain what goes wrong, understand what the OP is trying to accomplish or suggest a better way to do things.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with reflection:

```
public class RowHelper
{
    public static Row<object> LoadRow(object o)
    {
        var type = o.GetType();
        return new Row<object>
        {
            Name = (string)type.InvokeMember("Name", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, o, null),
            Value = type.InvokeMember("Value", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, o, null)
        };
    }
}
```

You would call this with:

```
var d = RowHelper.LoadRow(c);
```