# C# 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Char'.'

Tags: c#, casting

The following code creates an iterable of all the letters in the alphabet;

`var alphabet = Enumerable.Range('a', 26).Select(c => (char)c);`

Which works fine. However, the following doesn't work;

`var alphabet = Enumerable.Range('a', 26).Cast<char>();`

It throws an exception

> "System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Char'.'"

You may think this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59119260/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-int32-to-type-system-char) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085097/why-cant-i-unbox-an-int-as-a-decimal), but these relate to unboxing objects to a type that is not the original type. In this case, I have an `IEnumerable<int>`. Why can't I cast this element by element to `IEnumerable<char>`? They are both primitive types, not objects.

Comment: Linq performs a generic cast, meaning it has to be of that type or subtype. It doesn't look at any implicit or explicit operators

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 exactly. The exception is so clear, datatypes are conflicting.

Comment: @MosiaThabo What exactly do you mean "datatypes are conflicting"? A char is effectively an unsigned int under the hood. The problem is not a conflicting type, it is a failed cast.

Comment: Not really. A char is a char... int is an int. They both are datatypes and are not interchangeable unless casted.

Comment: The Error says "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Char" meaning int is not char and char is not int. But in practise you must cast these to either of them in order to achieve what you wish to achieve. that is like saying string "1" is an int. it may contain a number but it's not an integer unless casted to int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation for `Enumerable.Cast<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) states the following:

> The only type conversions that are performed by this method are reference conversions and unboxing conversions. The runtime type of the elements in the collection must match the target type, or in the case of value types, the runtime type of elements must be the result of a boxing conversion of the target type. Other conversion types, such as those between different numeric types, are not allowed.

So it seems, even though it is named `Cast`, it does not actually support casting values to different types.

Comment: It's meant for "converting" untyped collections to typed ones. This is particularly useful for pre-generic collections. Think of like `DataRowCollection` which only implements `IEnumerable` even though each object is a `DataRow`.

Comment: I see. I'm guessing this limitation is something low down in the framework. I wonder if that is because an array of primitives has a size of n x element size, since the values are inline in the array. However, an array of reference types has a size of n x [size of pointer] since it is an array of pointers to the heap. When you are iterating over an array of reference types, you are always iterating in steps of [size of pointer] whereas the step size when iterating over an array of primitives depends on the size of the elements...

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with arrays or even iteration.